# Purpose of Invoke-RestMethod in PowerBI report deployments

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am currently evaluating the efficiency of existing PowerBI deployment code written using Powershell script.

I found at several places the then developer called Invoke-RestMethod using URL as /groups/{$workspaceid} with POST method and bearer token in headers.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Method Post -Headers $headers -Verbose
```

Above method is called several times, especially after every New-PowerBIReport and Remove-PowerBIReport calls.

According to me, these calls are unnecessary, however, unable to get proper documentation around these calls to provide justification.
What this call will achieve? Any documentation link?

I found another call with the name as Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod.

What is the difference between Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod and Invoke-RestMethod?

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod is used to send/receive HTTP Request/Response to any server. Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod is used to send HTTP Request/Response to a BI Rest server.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.profile/invoke-powerbirestmethod?view=powerbi-ps

Comment: Thanks for the response! and what will Invoke-RestMethod will do if I send URL with just groups/workspaceid as a POST method?

Comment: Without seeing the actual code, my best bet is that the request sent to `groups/workspaceid` is meant to [create and/or update a group associated with the report's access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/create-group)

Comment: Think of Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod as an enhanced version of Invoke-RestMethod.  So there are additional method that are performed with Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod automatically.  If you use Invoke-RestMethod with a BI Server you need to add the equivalent code that Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod performs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the difference between Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod and Invoke-RestMethod?

Well according to the docs:

> Invokes a REST request against the Power BI service using the profile
> you're logged in with.

[Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.profile/invoke-powerbirestmethod?view=powerbi-ps)

So it's basically the same thing except you don't have to add the "bearer token in headers." yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So if we are passing URL as "https://app.powerbi.com/groups/$WorkSpaceId", what will be the response? I am just trying to check whether this call is really required after every other PowerBI API call like New-PowerBIReport, Remove-PowerBIReport etc.